Firebase cloud storage file name not bind with video link or not clickable
I am using firebase php Kreait as library for admin SDK this is the code below. I can view it using the url I generated
   $url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{$bucket->name()}/o/" . urlencode($storagePath) . "?alt=media";

My possible cause it that could it be how I am uploading the file? from the client to the server?
Im using this javascript files to get the upload video path
        var videoUpload = document.getElementById('videoUpload').files\[0\];

                const response = await axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: './http/Posthandler.php',
                    data: formData,
                    type: 'uploadVideo',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                });

the storage look like this enter image description here
but it needs to be something like this with clickable link
enter image description here



    public function uploadVideo($videoData, $videoTitle, $videoDescription, $userId)
    {
        try {
            $bucket = $this->cloudStorage->getBucket();
            $fileName = $videoTitle . '_' . time(); // Create a unique file name
            $storagePath = "videos/{$userId}/{$fileName}.mp4"; // Include the file name in the storage path
            // $stream = fopen($videoData['tmp_name'], 'r');
            $fileContents = file_get_contents($videoData['tmp_name']);

            // Upload the file
            $object = $bucket->upload($fileContents, [
                'name' => $storagePath,
                'metadata' => [
                    'contentType' => 'video/mp4', // Specify the content type
                ],
            ]);
   
            // if (is_resource($fileContents)) {
            //     fclose($stream);
            // }
            $url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{$bucket->name()}/o/" . urlencode($storagePath) . "?alt=media";
            
            $this->saveVideoData($videoTitle, $videoDescription, $url, $userId, $fileName);
            return ["success" => true, "message" => "Video uploaded successfully", "url" => $url];

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Log the error message and rethrow the exception
            error_log('Error uploading video: ' . $e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        }
    }

Ive tried using stream and object to upload it and it upload successfully the only problem is its not viewable directly on firebase console.
